# Is "Kinect for Ubuntu users" off topic question?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

Is [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52690/kinect-for-ubuntu-users) question off topic on Gaming SE? Why is this question off topic. How would you adjust it, where would you move it to be on topic?

Comment: This is kind of tangential with whether or not this question would've been on topic on this site, but the Ask Ubuntu moderators have accepted it for migration.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't say "Kinect for Ubuntu" as a subject is off-topic.  But let's look at what you said:

> Is it going to be possible to play games for Kinect device on Linux (Ubuntu) platform?

Speculation is off-topic.

> Could you write here some information about playing such games on this platform, if there are some problems.

Questions need to be specific, about real problems you face.  Asking people to list random information is not constructive.

> If there is a community around making Kinect games for Ubuntu and place where can I find some more information.

Development questions are off-topic, and we want our information to be self-contained.  External references are great, but we're not going to host answers just telling you to go somewhere else.

Overall I would have closed it as Not Constructive, and I've flagged it as such on Ubuntu as well.

The [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq) covers all of this and more; give it a good read.

Answer (score 5):

In the comments on your question, you posted [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26465/using-microsoft-kinect-on-a-pc) question as a justification for being on-topic.  I think that's a flawed argument because the core of the two questions are fundamentally different.

The windows question was asking whether the officially released Kinect SDK for Windows would allow for the Kinect to be used on the asker's Windows PC.  This is objectively answerable, because it is about one specific product that is already released.

Your Ubuntu question asks `Is it going to be possible to play games for Kinect`.  This inherently leads to speculation and is against the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).  Further, you ask for us to suggest a community working on Kinect support for Linux.  This is a recommendation which is also explicitly against the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

As such, I do believe that your question is off-topic

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that's the way to read the "recommendation" bit of the FAQ.

Comment: As one of the people who voted to close this is why I did not change my vote. Specific question vs wide open question.